# If I have a table that has 100 fields does that indicate bad database design?

Tags: database-design

I have a table: Order Detail. An Order has many details, in my case 100 fields. Is it common in databases to have 100 fields in a table or should I be looking to break it up into smaller tables and how? Thanks!

Some of the data in the Order Detail table is used by Sales Managers, other data is used by Product Line Specialists, and yet other data is used by Purchasing.

Should I keep it all together or should I break it apart and which NF would apply to this level?

Comment: do you have a lot of data that is repeated? that's the biggest sign that your db design is bad

Comment: Some designs have 300 fields on a table and that may be the correct (!?) design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Of course there can be as many fields as required and the number of fields in a given database does not indicate poor design. However, what *can* indicate poor design is (as Kshitij Mehta points out in the comment) a high degree of data replication (or poor [*normalisation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Normalization is the process of organizing data in a database. This includes creating tables and establishing relationships between those tables according to rules designed both to protect the data and to make the database more flexible by eliminating redundancy and inconsistent dependency.

The objectives of normalization beyond 1NF (First Normal Form) were stated as follows by Codd:

1. To free the collection of relations from undesirable insertion, update and deletion dependencies;
2. To reduce the need for restructuring the collection of relations, as new types of data are introduced, and thus increase the life span of application programs;
3. To make the relational model more informative to users;
4. To make the collection of relations neutral to the query statistics, where these statistics are liable to change as time goes by. —E.F. Codd, "Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model"

It is common for databases to be normalised to 2NF, and in certain cases higher...

See Wikipedia or [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878) for more information. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data in the table is normalized, there isn't much benefit in splitting it up into multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know two things:  how to normalize and when to normalize.

If you already know how to normalize, and the table is as normalized as you can get it, then don't split it just for the sake of good design.  If you don't know how to normalize, see some of the other responses.

The answer to when to normalize is more subtle.  There are experts who recommend normalize all the way, all the time.  There are other experts who don't.  My answer is to normalize unless you have a better plan, for the case at hand.

For me, if the case at hand is a reporting database, a data mart, or a data warehouse,  I prefer star schema or snowflake schema to normalized design.  Even when I'm normalizing, I hardly ever worry about normalization forms past BCNF.